# Display all associated entries django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have the following models:

A project model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=180)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    IN_PROGRESS = 'Manuscript in Progress'
    COLLABORATORS_NEEDED = 'Looking for Collaborators'
    REVIEW = 'Manuscript Under Revision'
    SUBMITTED = 'Manuscript Submitted'

    CURRENT_STATUS_CHOICES = ((IN_PROGRESS, 'Manuscript In Progress'),     (COLLABORATORS_NEEDED, 'Looking for Collaborators'), (REVIEW, 'Manuscript Under Revision'), (SUBMITTED, 'Manuscript Submitted'))
    current_status  = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices = CURRENT_STATUS_CHOICES, default=IN_PROGRESS)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-title', '-current_status', 'active', '-updated']
```

and a job (HelpWanted) model associated with the Project model:

```
class HelpWanted(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)

    STATISTICIAN = 'Statistical or Quantitative'
    DATA_ENTRY = 'Data Entry'
    RESEARCH = 'Literature Review'
    OTHER = 'Other'

    POSITION_CHOICES = ((STATISTICIAN, 'Statistical or Quantitative'), (DATA_ENTRY,'Data Entry'), (RESEARCH, 'Literature Review'), (OTHER,'Other'))
    Position = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=POSITION_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(null = True, auto_now = False, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null = True, auto_now = False, blank=True)
    time_commitment = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    # slug = models.SlugField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.Position)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name=u'Available Position'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Available Positions'
```

I want to have an all_jobs listing page, but want to have a header of each project followed by the associated jobs.

I.e. If I have a project called "Ice Cream Stand" and there are 3 jobs:

1. Buyer
2. Maker
3. Seller

I want to be able to display:

**Ice Cream Stand**

1. Buyer
2. Maker
3. Seller

I can't seem to get the `for` loop right, if I'm supposed to be using a `for` loop in the template.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your template was given a variable called `projects` that is a queryset of all projects, you could do:

```
{% for project in projects %}
  <h1>{{ project.title }}</h1>
  <ol>
    {% for help in project.helpwanted_set.all %}
      <li>{{ help.Position }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ol>
{% endfor %}
```

You could also pass in a variable called, say, `positions`, that is the queryset of all positions available, and use the [`regroup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) template tag to display them:

```
{% regroup positions by project as positions_list %}
{% for project in positions_list %}
  <h1>{% project.grouper %}</h1>
  <ol>
    {% for position in project.list %}
      <li>{{ position.Position }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ol>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to name the foreignkey used in HelpWanted models like that:

```
project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='jobs')
```

After that you can, in your view, load your project with all the jobs related to it in one query with:

```
Project.objects.(your filter).select_related().prefetch_related('jobs')
```

And in your template use

```
{{ project }}
<ul>
{% for job in project.jobs.all %}
    <li>{{ job }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Hope that can help you ;)

Comment: Why do you insist on adding the related_name? The models work perfectly well as they are, using the automatic related_name of `helpwanted_set`. And you shouldn't be randomly using both `select_related` and `prefetch_related`.

Comment: Yep I think that only prefetch_related method do the job. Concerning the related_name, it is just an habit that I have to easily retrieve foreignkey.